# Why is "I'll see you on next Tuesday afternoon" wrong but "on Tuesday" isn't?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

- *I'll see you on Tuesday*.
- *I'll see you on next Tuesday afternoon.*

Does anyone know why the second sentence is wrong?  Please help - I need the grammar rule!

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not the time of day is mentioned, we don't use both *on* and *next* together.

On Saturday we might say 'I'll see you on Tuesday' (the Tuesday of the coming week).

In the early part of the week, we might say 'I'll see you next Tuesday' (Tuesday of the next week).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the grammar rule, but the second one would be correct as
"*I'll see you next Tuesday afternoon*".

The *on* is unnecessary there.

Comment: *I'll see you on Tuesday afternoon* is also correct. You can have *on* or *next* but not both here.